# Unable to install extensions in Visual studio 2019 and it fails with error Invalid TimeStamp or Digital Signature as none

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am unable to install most of the Visual studio extensions(Ex: Episerver, NPM Task runner). During the installation it shows “Digital Signature: Invalid TimeStamp” or “Digital Signature: Null”. Although for some extensions it is showing “Digital Signature: Invalid TimeStamp” but it successfully completes the installation.(Ex: Microsoft visual studio installer projects)
Visual studio Community edition version: 16.6.5 (2019).

Below is the error log:
8/7/2020 10:12:29 AM - Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
8/7/2020 10:12:29 AM - Found 'C:\USERS\SARRMARPA\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\16.0_6EE4662A\EXTENSIONS\pondhjej.glj\extension.vsixmanifest'
8/7/2020 10:12:29 AM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\10\Desktop SDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
8/7/2020 10:12:29 AM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\10\SDK ARM Additions\extension.vsixmanifest'
8/7/2020 10:12:29 AM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\10\Windows Store SDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
8/7/2020 10:12:29 AM - Skipping 'C:\Users\sarrmarpa\AppData\Local\Microsoft SDKs' as it doesn't exist
8/7/2020 10:12:29 AM - Beginning to install extension to Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019...
8/7/2020 10:12:29 AM - VSIX TaskScheduler: VSIX Update Configuration task has not been successfully registered.
8/7/2020 10:12:29 AM - No mapping between account names and security IDs was done
8/7/2020 10:13:18 AM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Windows.UniversalCRT.Msu.8: The current OS Version '6.3.9600.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.2,6.3)'.
8/7/2020 10:13:18 AM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.VisualStudio.NuGet.PowershellBindingRedirect: The current OS Version '6.3.9600.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.2)'.
8/7/2020 10:13:18 AM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Windows.UniversalCRT.Msu.7: The current OS Version '6.3.9600.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.2)'.
8/7/2020 10:13:18 AM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.KB2882822.Win7: The current OS Version '6.3.9600.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.2)'.
8/7/2020 10:13:18 AM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Azure.PowerShellNew: Required conditions are not satisfied: Powershell5
8/7/2020 10:13:18 AM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Graphics.EnableTools: The current OS Version '6.3.9600.0' is not in the supported version range '10.0.10240'.
8/7/2020 10:13:19 AM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools.WindowsIdentityFoundation.Msu: The current OS Version '6.3.9600.0' is not in the supported version range '(,6.2)'.
8/7/2020 10:13:19 AM - System restore is not supported on this system
8/7/2020 10:13:19 AM - Failed to create system restore point: 0x80131524
8/7/2020 10:13:44 AM - Certificate is invalid: EPiServer.VsIntegration.Package.vsix
8/7/2020 10:13:44 AM - Cache failed. Retrying download of 'EPiServer.CMS.B7A45E5E-3836-4864-A117-95207E71A9B3,version=11.7.0.437'.
8/7/2020 10:13:44 AM - Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uri
8/7/2020 10:13:44 AM - Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uri
8/7/2020 10:13:44 AM - Activity threw exception System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uri
8/7/2020 10:13:44 AM - Skipping cache of package 'EPiServer.CMS.B7A45E5E-3836-4864-A117-95207E71A9B3,version=11.7.0.437' since installing or downloading it failed
8/7/2020 10:13:44 AM - Skipping cache of package 'Component.EPiServer.CMS.B7A45E5E-3836-4864-A117-95207E71A9B3,version=11.7.0.437' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
8/7/2020 10:14:17 AM - Install Error : System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package 'EPiServer.CMS.B7A45E5E-3836-4864-A117-95207E71A9B3' failed to download
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.b__14_0()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.Install() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress, Version targetedVsVersion) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp) ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package 'EPiServer.CMS.B7A45E5E-3836-4864-A117-95207E71A9B3' failed to download at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.<Install>b__14_0() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---

Comment: Try to remove the EPI Server extension

Comment: Epi server extension has not been added to the installed extensions

Comment: It is listed in your log!

Comment: @rahulmarpally,any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle this issue and let us know if it helps or not.

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to install extensions in Visual studio 2019 and it fails with
> error Invalid TimeStamp or Digital Signature as none

Please try the following steps to troubleshoot your issue:

**1)** go to the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community \Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` and check if you have this dll

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.DeployWizard.dll

enter `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE` and check if you have this dll

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.WizardFramework.dll

**Then**, please rename these two dlls to other names or just delete them.

**After that**, restart your computer to test again.

**Also**, enter `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft` and check if you has a folder called `VSI`.

**If so**, please rename this folder to another name or just delete it.

**2)** disable any VS third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**

**3)** turn off any third party software, anti-virus and firewall

**4)** [reset VS settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/resetsettings-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019)

**5)** [repair VS in the VS Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or if there is new release vs version, please update VS.

**Also**, check if you have any OS update, if so, please update it.

**6)** delete any `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx` folders and then restart VS to test again.

**7)** At last, if all the steps do not work, reinstalling VS might be a choice. Although it will spend lots of time, I think you could have a try.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have tried most of the above troubleshooting steps but it did not work out for me, I will verify if anti-virus or firewall is blocking the installation and keep you posted.

Comment: Okay. Besides, you can also run `sfc /scannow` in CMD(run as administrator) to check whether there are some broken os files.  Besides, if these do not help, try to reinstall VS.